# Is creating VeraCrypt volumes from the command line less secure than using the GUI?

Tags: veracrypt

I've been using TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt for several years, but I've only recently started using it extensively from the command line. I know that the functions in the command line and GUI versions are the same, *but* when you create an encrypted volume with the GUI VeraCrypt invites you to move the mouse on the screen for a better randomisation of the key. Nothing similar happens with the command line. Does this mean the latter approach is less secure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VeraCrypt has an equivalent mechanism in command line. When you create an encrypted volume, you can pass a file in option as a source of randomness with the `--random-source` option :

> --random-source=FILE
> Use FILE as a source of random data (e.g., when creating a volume) instead  of requiring the user to type random characters.

If you don't pass this option, VeraCrypt should prompt you with:

> Please type at least 320 randomly chosen characters and then press Enter:

That's the text equivalent of moving the mouse in graphical mode.